# Resizing Drop Down Menu Height

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I can resize the items in the list height by using the measure item event and changing the itemheight but that doesnt change the main objects item height, but I want to resize the actual height of the drop down box itself.

e.g.

[image]

should be (exaggerated):

[image]

Comment: Please add appropriate tag - winorms? asp.net?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using winforms, try changing the font size of the combobox.

Comment: I know chaging the font size allows this, I was looking for a method that leaves the font size as its current size. Thank you though

Comment: @cookies Unfortunately, short of creating your own control, I don't think there is a way. I got around this by creating a WPF control using a, wait for it, WPF combobox. Unlike the winforms versions, you can resize them all you want and maintain the text. Make sure you make the WPF control part of your project solution and it will become available as a add-in control to your winforms project. It's a little more work than you wanted, but should do the trick.

Comment: thank you - I will have a look into it, was hoping there would be a nice solution :') no issue with creating a custom control tho.